# Store Form Values In Cookie

Tags: php, javascript, forms, cookies, setcookie

I've been trying to teach myself about cookies for the last couple of hours and how I would go about storing values from a few form fields into a cookie.

Im not having much luck, all the examples I've found havent been very helpful.
Should I generate them using PHP or JS?
Any feedback or a kick in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/yucM7/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Storing form values in a cookie doesn't make much sense.  What's your end goal?  You might be better off going with storing them in a session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxqb6/2/).

All you need is jQuery and [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Keep in mind, there're couple of changes in html code.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function() {
   // serialize our form (get string containing field names and values)
   dataString = $(this).serialize();
   // set new cookie
   $.cookie('formCookie', dataString);
   return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#getCookie', function() {
   // get serialized string from cookie    
   cookieData = $.cookie('formCookie');
   // if cookie exists continue
   if (cookieData != null) {
        // split cookieData string into an array of fields and their values
        cookieArray = cookieData.split('&');
        // go through each field and split it too to get field name and it's value
        $.each(cookieArray, function(k, v) {
          field = v.split('=');
          // populate field with data
          $('#myForm [name="'+field[0]+'"]').val(field[1]);
        });
    }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Kane, Thank you very much for the example, the comments are fantastic. How would I go about it if I didn't want to store all the field values in the form. For example I only wanted to store the first name and last name?

Comment: @Jamesil, Here's a modified version of code above: http://jsfiddle.net/Xxqb6/3/. Basically, to every input field or any other field you add class, in my example it's "subset" and then you just use same serialize() function, but instead of using $(this).serialize(), we'll use $('.subset').serialize();

Comment: Cheers!! thats working well. Just one last question. If I put an '@' in a field (for an email address) and save it to the cookie, it returns a '%40'. How can I go about preventing that??

Comment: @Jamesil, add an if else check if field name is email related and then instead of using val(field[1]); use val(decodeURIComponent(field[1]));

Comment: Worked like a charm!  But the spaces in the fields are being decoded, they are still appearing with a '+' symbol.  I thought the val(decodeURIComponent(field[1]));  would have fixed all the decoding of characters and spaces?

Comment: @Jamesil, probably could be handled with val(decodeURIComponent(field[1]).replace('+', ' ')). But it'll work only if you're sure that there won't be any actual plus signs in any of the fields, otherwise i'd recommend writing separate function instead of serialize() which will be handling input/select/radio input with encodeURIcompontnet() function.

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookie using Javascript by following (Refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

**Setting cookie using Jquery:** `$.cookie("example", "foo");`

Alternatively you can set your cookie from server by :

```
<?php
    $value = 'something from somewhere';
    setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
```